# How to create bar chart with secondary_y from dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I want to create a bar chart of two series (say 'A' and 'B') contained in a Pandas dataframe. If I wanted to just plot them using a **different y-axis**, I can use `secondary_y`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=10).reshape(5,2),columns=['A','B'])
df['A'] = df['A'] * 100
df.plot(secondary_y=['A'])
```

but if I want to create bar graphs, the equivalent command **is ignored** (it doesn't put different scales on the y-axis), so the bars from 'A' are so big that the bars from 'B' are cannot be distinguished:

```
df.plot(kind='bar',secondary_y=['A'])
```

How can I do this in pandas directly? or how would you create such graph?

*I'm using pandas 0.10.1 and matplotlib version 1.2.1.*

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent command does not work? Do you have no figure, or is the figure not what you expect?

Comment: please post the error or describe what is not working

Comment: What have you tried to implement this by hand?  Have you looked at the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html)?

Comment: No, everything goes smoothly. Do you get same sized bars? Which versions are you using?

Comment: I *see*, sorry, I was totally missing that crucial line (now obvious in retrospect). This doesn't work in pandas 0.11 either, I recommend submitting this as [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) on github.

Comment: Filed an issue https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3598

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't think pandas graphing supports this.   Did some manual matplotlib code.. you can tweak it further

```
import pylab as pl
fig = pl.figure()
ax1 = pl.subplot(111,ylabel='A')
#ax2 = gcf().add_axes(ax1.get_position(), sharex=ax1, frameon=False, ylabel='axes2')
ax2 =ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('B')
ax1.bar(df.index,df.A.values, width =0.4, color ='g', align = 'center')
ax2.bar(df.index,df.B.values, width = 0.4, color='r', align = 'edge')
ax1.legend(['A'], loc = 'upper left')
ax2.legend(['B'], loc = 'upper right')
fig.show()
```

[image]

I am sure there are ways to force the one bar further tweak it.  move bars further apart, one slightly transparent etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had the same problem recently and even if it's an old question, I think that I can give an answer for this problem, in case if someone else lost his mind with this. Joop gave the bases of the thing to do, and it's easy when you only have (for exemple) two columns in your dataframe, but it becomes really nasty when you have a different numbers of columns for the two axis, due to the fact that you need to play with the position argument of the pandas plot() function. In my exemple I use seaborn but it's optionnal :

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[i*99 for i in range(11)]]).transpose(), columns = ["100"], index = [i for i in range(11)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[i for i in range(11)], [i*2 for i in range(11)]]).transpose(), columns = ["1", "2"], index = [i for i in range(11)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

# we must define the length of each column. 
df1_len = len(df1.columns.values)
df2_len = len(df2.columns.values)
column_width = 0.8 / (df1_len + df2_len)

# we calculate the position of each column in the plot. This value is based on the position definition :
# Specify relative alignments for bar plot layout. From 0 (left/bottom-end) to 1 (right/top-end). Default is 0.5 (center)
# http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html
df1_posi = 0.5 + (df2_len/float(df1_len)) * 0.5
df2_posi = 0.5 - (df1_len/float(df2_len)) * 0.5

# In order to have nice color, I use the default color palette of seaborn
df1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, width=column_width*df1_len, color=sns.color_palette()[:df1_len], position=df1_posi)
df2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, width=column_width*df2_len, color=sns.color_palette()[df1_len:df1_len+df2_len], position=df2_posi)

ax.legend(loc="upper left")

# Pandas add line at x = 0 for each dataframe.
ax.lines[0].set_visible(False)
ax2.lines[0].set_visible(False)

# Specific to seaborn, we have to remove the background line 
ax2.grid(b=False, axis='both')

# We need to add some space, the xlim don't manage the new positions
column_length = (ax2.get_xlim()[1] - abs(ax2.get_xlim()[0])) / float(len(df1.index))
ax2.set_xlim([ax2.get_xlim()[0] - column_length, ax2.get_xlim()[1] + column_length])

fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
plt.show()
```

And the result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZjK8.png

I didn't test every possibilities but it looks like it works fine whatever the number of columns in each dataframe you use.